# What is the implementation below the isInteger() function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I used a Number Object Method in JS which is `isInteger(num)`. This function returns "true" if num is an Integer and vice versa. I want to understand how this function works but can't figure it out.
So, I want to ask:

1. What is the implementation of `isInteger()` function in JS? (the logic)
2. Is there any reference website to see the implementation of other build-in methods in JS?

Comment: Implementations are hardly interesting, [the standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number.isinteger) might be ..?

Comment: `isInteger` might not be implemented in JS.